# Syslog directory doesn't exist

Tags: c, linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, syslog

so I'm using Debian on my personal windows laptop.
I'm doing an assignment that entails using the syslog c library to print from my program when the statements run.

Here's the relevant code I used in my program:

```
#include <syslog.h>
```

(then in main)

```
openlog("slog",LOG_PID|LOG_CONS,LOG_USER);
syslog(LOG_INFO,"wuddup to u");
closelog();
```

There's no issues with the code running, but I can't find any file that has the log I printed.

on Debian, syslog is supposed to be saved in either in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages.
/var/log exists, but I don't have either of these folders inside it.

It doesn’t appear to be in a hidden file, so I don't imagine it's a permission problem.
syslog.conf which should be located in /etc also doesn’t exist.

However,
there is a reference to syslog in rsyslog.conf which does exist in /etc

a section within rsyslog.conf titled RULES starts like this:

```
#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
```

I haven’t figured out what the dashes or the rest of it could really mean.
Here’s the output for some possibly relevant commands I tried in the terminal:

***dmesg***

```
[    0.007738]  Microsoft 4.4.0-18362.1049-Microsoft 4.4.35
```

***uname -a***

```
Linux DESKTOP-KH1LDFG 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #1049-Microsoft Thu Aug 14 12:01:00 PST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

***find /syslog***

```
find: ‘/syslog’: No such file or directory
```

***sudo apt-get install syslog***

```
[sudo] password for sarah:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package syslog
```

***mkdir syslog*** (from /var/log)

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘syslog’: Permission denied
```

***sudo service rsyslog start***

```
[....] Starting enhanced syslogd: rsyslogdrsyslogd: set SO_TIMESTAMP failed on '/dev/log': Invalid argument [v8.1901.0]
rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): No such file or directory.
rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
. ok
```

Comment: What is the significance of the dash `-` in front of `-/var/log/user.log`?  Does it mean the rule is disabled, or the file must already exist (but it doesn't) or something?  The last line should control where `LOG_USER` entries go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler According to [this](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html#regular-file) the `-` prefix is to omit syncing after every log entry.

Comment: @IanAbbott: There is more than one syslog or syslogd package around; I wasn't sure if the one used by Debian is the one from https://www.rsyslog.com/ or not.  The dash is not relevant to the problem, I think.

Comment: The platform appears to be partly Microsoft, partly Linux — a curious combination.  On the RHEL 7.4 machine I use, `/var/log/messages` is a file; there is no `/var/log/syslog` file or directory.  Can you see the syslog daemon running?  Try `ps -ef | grep '[s]yslog'` and see what it shows — I get an entry with `/usr/sbin/rsyslogd` as the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Debian's rsyslog is from rsyslog.com with some patches. The use of the `-` prefix seems pretty standard as installed by Debian.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OP's Debian will be running under WSL2 on Windows 10, which uses a Linux kernel built by Microsoft. Steve Ballmer would be turning in his grave if he was dead.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Maybe it's a way to create a 'perpetual motion machine' — have SB turning in his grave?

Comment: According to your `uname -a` command, you're running WSL. On WSL, rsyslogd isn't started by default. Try starting it first with `sudo service rsyslog start`.

Comment: so the ps -ef grep command didn't show anything and it appears the rsyslog start command was denied- I added the output to my question. I was also going to try removing the dash from in front of the syslog path in rsyslog.conf but linux warned me against changing a readonly file, so I didn't commit to it.

Comment: The `ps` is not going to show rsyslog if it isn't started, and it seems like you are unable to start it for some reason. I'd suggest you update WSL to WSL 2 and then reinstall rsyslog if the issue persists. You can find instruction on how to upgrade to WSL 2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).  Also, do not worry about the dash in front of the syslog path in the config file: Dash means to not synchronize the log file to the disk every time there is a write, if the sync option is on by default.

Comment: Also, the error shown after you attempted to start rsyslog pertains to the kernel network socket `/dev/log`, which is what rsyslogd listens to for logs. The `/proc/kmsg` that's referenced in the error is also a kernel log buffer, which is more reason for you to update your kernel and possibly reinstall rsyslog with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog`

Comment: omg this worked!! so I didn't check between commands but I ran 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog' followed by 'sudo apt-get install wsl' and then I recompiled my program and ran it again. Then I checked the files in /var/log and syslog was there! with my log messages!! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran

```
'sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog'
```

followed by

```
'sudo apt-get install wsl'
```

and then I recompiled my program and ran it again. Then I checked the files in /var/log and syslog was there! with my log messages!! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about a few things - they *might* be problems: 1) `Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)` is *NOT* always exactly like a "true" Linux.  You might find differences between WSL and, say, Debian installed on a VM.  2) I'm not sure about `slog` in your openlog().  Did you configure "slog" as a valid user?  3) Most importantly, I'm not sure you need `openlog()/closelog()` at all.  I believe you can simply call [syslog()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog).